# Change ViewController by call presentViewController and UITransitionView

Tags: ios, iphone, swift, uiviewcontroller

I find out that when you call a viewController by presentViewController 
a class type of UITransitionView appear behind your called viewController and present it as first view.

I have a view in AppDelegate that fixed in all layouts if you call another viewControl like below.
[image]

but problem was that you can't tap on UIButtons on view in AppDelegate.

Answer (score -1):

I found that we can catch this class by

> NSClassFromString

and resize it as we need. below code is my solution.

```
let appDel = UIApplication.sharedApplication().delegate as! AppDelegate
    let superView = appDel.window?.subviews

    if let transitonViewClass = NSClassFromString("UITransitionView") {
        for subV in (superView)! where subV.isKindOfClass(transitonViewClass) {

//screenAutoLayoutCalc is my own function to make application responsive to all devices

            subV.frame = self.view.screenAutoLayoutCalc(0, y: 0, w: 1242, h: 1996)
        }
    }
```